# Are the results of the Candidate Search correct

Tags: support, jobs, search

I was just trying out the Candidate Search on careers to find my own profile with some parameters where I expected that I get listed nearly at the top of the search results. But with no success. I´m even not on the first page.

I have a profile at careers, my **location is Siegen, Germany** and I´m in the **"Top 10%" for C#** at stack overflow. So I started my Candidate search using `C#` in the field "Who or what" and `Siegen` in the field "Where". I have not made any changes to the "Location Details" or checked/unchecked any options to filter the results.

This is the result that I get.

[image]

So, is this result correct to the search that I made? Is it because I´m trying it out (demo-mode) and not registered as employer?

I really expected to get candidates that have a location next to Siegen and are specialist in C# listed higher up in the search results

Comment: @rene. seems to match. I wait another day and evaluate the behavior again. When the results are better I delete my question

Comment: @rene well, turns out that's not the case as Nick now answered. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location is just a filter, not a ranking mechanism, i.e. you're either in the results or out of the results only.  Location searches are not exact; they use a bounding box which often includes areas that are not in the same colloquial district.  This is especially true of larger areas and by default we expand the bounding box by miles which you can edit in the location drop down.

As for searching for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), there are lots of places where tags exist on profiles, and the SO tags score is only one part of the ranking algorithm.

Comment: Totally off topic but just curious, why "NickLarsen" and not "Nick Larsen" as your display name?

Comment: It's my username across many sites on the internet and most sites don't allow spaces in names so when I created it some 5 years ago, that's just how it came out.  I just updated it.